# Bootstrap menu is resizing wrong

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need make menu in center of page. And on right side I need lane of white empty space. It's working with 100% resize. But when I zoom out screen it doesn't stay in same position.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row header">
  <div class="row menu col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php" style="background-color: #be5f28;">Úvod</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

}

.header .container {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Here is situation with 100%
http://postimg.org/image/jyj7ylr0z/

and here with 25% zoom out
http://postimg.org/image/yshws51kl/

**demo**: http://zssever.damidev.com/

Comment: Way too little info, I'm afraid. You'll need to link to a working example to get specific help. Your code shows no attempt to center the navigation.

Comment: http://zssever.damidev.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the biggest blunder that I saw was overriding the 'margin-left' property of 'container' class. This should not be done. 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' should be left to 'auto' because that is what responsible for horizontally centering a component.

The html markup should be like:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row menu col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-3 ">
        <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
            <li>
```

A few minor adjustments need to be made but that was the solution to your problem. Once the layout is fixed, the menu won't deviate from its position on changing zoom value

Comment: Ok! thank.. that is better. But still I have problem with empty white space on right side. background-color must be with class menu? and how can I make this white space to end of right side of page? thanks

Comment: You can put a float: left on menu class. And just for your information you have update changes to your website but due to this '<base href="http://127.0.0.1:81/projects/damidev/">' no css and images are being loaded. You need to change the path